# Openfoam error - Unknown rhoReactionThermo type

Tags: openfoam

I am running a multiphase DPM simulation using spray foam, where I am injecting water droplets inside a domain to study the evaporation rate.

When I run the case I get the following error. If any one could guide me what the error is would be really helpful.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUllq.png)

Injecting water droplets inside the domain to study evaporation rate